# ResetDatabase Fullsync transaction does not sync local client database

Tags: convertigo

I've added a `ResetDatabase` Transaction in my fullsync connector in order to clean up the whole couchDB database.
Surprinsigly, clients are not sync when I run this transaction. I need to manually clean local client database in order to refresh all the datas. Is it a normal behaviour ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: What versions of Convertigo server and Client SDK are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Convertigo mobile builder 7.5.6. Server is local dev or trial convertigo server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client database cleaning when the CouchDB server has been reset has only been implemented since Convertigo 7.6.0: https://github.com/convertigo/convertigo/issues/22